# Adding Column to Table

Tags: tables

```
\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{Risk Analysis} \label{tab:title} 
 \begin{tabulary}{0.7\textwidth}{LCL}
  Risk      & \ Probability (1-5)  & \ Impact (1-5)  \\
\hline
Software cannot be completed on time. & 2 & 5  \\
System requirements not adequately identified. & 3 & 5 \\
\end{tabulary}  
\end{center}
```

Have a table above, I am trying to create another column called 'Priority (1-5) - ideas on how to do that?

---

When I add an extra column, LaTeX throws up and says

> `Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. (\end{tabulary} ...)`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Do some research on [how tables work in LaTeX](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables).

Comment: I have done so but I get an 'Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. (\end{tabulary} ...)

Comment: Well, then I'd edit that into your question.  See also the edit to my answer (coming soon to a store near you!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't find an existing question that dealt with this directly, I'll put this here.  I would first suggest taking a look at the [LaTeX WikiBook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables); it is extremely helpful while learning.

Take a look at how things are organized in a LaTeX table:

```
\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{Risk Analysis} \label{tab:title} 
 \begin{tabulary}{0.7\textwidth}{LCL}
  Risk                   & Probability (1-5) & Impact (1-5)  \\ \hline
  Software cannot be ... & 2                 & 5             \\
  System requirements... & 3                 & 5             \\
\end{tabulary}  
\end{center}
```

Can you extrapolate?  Note: the `LCL` bit is the alignment (in this case `left,center,left`) of the columns; adding another column will necessitate another alignment character.  The cause of your error arose from the lack of this extra alignment character; LaTeX ran into another column and had no idea what to do with it.

Comment: I can extrapolate the rows but not the columns ;x

Comment: @user1249957 see the edit.

Comment: You're very welcome.  If it works (and if it's clear why it works), consider [accepting it](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852) as the answer.

Comment: Trying to extrapolate the columns and it is still struggling ;x

Comment: Worked it out, need to change {LCL} brilliant :)

Comment: @user1249957 Exactly. ;)